# Prevent "New Order" Notification Checkboxes from Being Re-Checked Automatically

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I've edited the adminhtml template for these checkboxes (totals.phtml) and successfully removed the "checked" attribute that causes them to be checked by default. Now, when the New Order page first loads for the admin, these boxes are checked. However, as soon as I perform an action on the page (such as adding a product to the order), the boxes become rechecked automatically. How can I prevent this behavior?

[image]

The problem ended up being that certain actions (like adding products) would reload the page using the core /vendor template file vs. my module's

Answer (score 0):

Go to the same file  `module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/totals.phtml`

Replace the whole div (line approx. 27)

```
<div class="admin__field admin__field-option field-email-order-confirmation">
        <input type="checkbox" id="send_confirmation" name="order[send_confirmation]" value="0"
               class="admin__control-checkbox"/>
        <label for="send_confirmation" class="admin__field-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email Order Confirmation')) ?></label>
```

I have removed the `checked="true"` and make `value="0"` on the same field.

There is an event that is also triggered at the end of the `totals.phtml`.

Comment: The problem ended up being that certain actions (like adding products) would reload the page using the core /vendor template file vs. my module's

Comment: have you overridden the file? which files? try to change the id value from `send_confirmation` to `send_confirmation_no` if you really want to get rid off.